# How can I display an ExtJS 5 datepicker when clicking a highcharts rangeselector field?

Tags: extjs, highcharts, datepicker

I am using ExtJS 5 on my web application with Highcharts. Currently, the rangeselector date input fields are just text fields and I would like to have a datepicker for these fields instead. The datepicker must be an ExtJS datepicker and not a jQuery datepicker, as I need my entire application to have consistent datepicker fields throughout my application. Is there some way to implement this?

Comment: Defaulty the datepicker can be initialised in the callback, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/ so you can try use extJS datepicker in similar way.

Comment: I am not looking to use jquery. I only want to use the ExtJS datepicker. I've tried using the ExtJS datepicker in the date query, but every time I try to render it to the highcharts range selector fields, nothing happens.